# Include another template with a variabile in dwoo

Tags: php, include, template-engine, dwoo

Actually I'm using dwoo a PHP5 Template Engine. I configured it, used some of its functions but the only problem that I found for now it's including a template with a variable. I mean

I know that I can include another template from the template with:

```
{include(file='sect_header_stuff.tpl')}
```

But actually I need to include a sub_template with a simple variable, for example:

```
{$include}
```

That's because this variable will have different template to include according to condition that I specific in a php file.

I tried something like this, a basic example:

```
$dwoo = new Dwoo\Core();
$params = array();
$params['include'] = $dwoo->get("sub_template.tpl");
echo $dwoo->get("template.tpl", $params);
```

But nothing to do.. any idea for resolving this issue?